# What crops benefit the most from AgTech and particularly soil monitoring?

Tags: agriculture

I am trying to understand the benefits of AgTech for different crops, and particularly IoT-based solutions like soil sensors (humidity, temperature, NPK). What are the crops that are benefitting the most today from this technology?

I would assume that it would be more beneficial for crops with high yield per Hectare, e.g. bananas would benefit more than corn. Is that the case?

Comment: "benefit the most" as measured by which metric?

Comment: Economically, either as increased yield or reduced costs.

Comment: Given that, I fail to see how the question is on topic here.